How to assign a default security row for RLS in Power BI workspaces?
I have a power BI dataset that I'm looking to give access to a large population of the company. I don't want to have to go through and assign every person to a security role through the GUI. Is there a way I can set a default PowerBI RLS security role or assign it automatically to my users?
